# A pack of 2n cards, n of which are red, and another n are black. It is divided into two equal parts and a card is drawn from each part.

Tags: probability

***A pack of 2n cards, n of which are red, and another n are black. It is divided into two equal parts and a card is drawn from each part. Find the probability that the cards drawn are of the same colour.***

This is what I have done:
 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEPOJ.jpg)

And this is what the book has done: 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTUjR.jpg)

Please say me who is correct.
 ( I am unable to do formatting in text as I don't have a net connection on PC)

Comment: Both are the same!

Comment: Please can you explain how?

Comment: Well the only different thing is the index in the sum, but for the cases $k=0,k=n$ the argument of the sum is 0. You both got $$\sum _{k=0}^n2\frac{k(n-k)}{n^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me